# Display blank with core-image-sato image on custom intel board

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, x11, display, yocto

I have a braswell based custom Intel Board.

Downloaded latest poky source code from git repository and added the meta-intel layer to it.

```
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-intel
```

Selected the Machine in local.conf

```
MACHINE = "intel-corei7-64"
```

Generated a `core-image-full-cmdline` image and it displays the Yocto Splash screen and starts the command line which I am able to Login using username 'root'

But when I generate a `core-image-sato` or `core-image-x11`, when it loads displays Yocto Splash Screen and the screen is blank. Neither command line neither GUI.

How to debug this scenario. What I am missing. Do I have to make any modifications. Thanks for your help

Comment: you need to start with your xorg config

Comment: Do we have manually modify this after copying root filesystem

Comment: yes, configure x and try to manually start it

Comment: The current default image by default starts GUI.. What should I do it to start command line for my manual configuration